# Enabling Details HTTP Errors for a certain network in IIS 7

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7

I have a Windows server running for development and I noticed that on my local machine which uses the local network to communicate to the server I get non-detailed error messages from IIS.  For example, when my ColdFusion server throws an error, I get the standard IIS 500 error.

I figured out how to enable showing detailed errors, but that shows detailed errors for all clients.  Is it possible to only enable details errors for a single subnet (192.168.34.0/24) and show the non-detailed errors for any other client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since you're on IIS7 you can use URL Rewrite.  [Here's a blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/07/29/troubleshoot-asp-net-errors-remotely-while-appearing-local.aspx) I put together on achieving what you're asking about.

Comment: That just seems like such an inconvenient way to do things.  I would think Windows would make it a bit easier than that, but I guess if that's what I gotta do.

Comment: Yes I agree.  I've thought for years that it would be nice to have an ApprovedIPs type property for detailed errors.  Since it doesn't, that URL Rewrite workaround will do the trick.